# PowerPoint export to pdf removes bold

Tags: pdf, microsoft-office, fonts, microsoft-powerpoint

I have an issue since I switched to the [Open Sans](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Open+Sans) font in my Power Point presentation. In PowerPoint it looks fine (correct font, correct bold). However when I export it to PDF the bold formatting is removed.

What I am doing

1. Installed all the [Open Sans](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Open+Sans) fonts available from the website, one by one
2. Change some text in my pptx to that font, and format it bold
3. File > Export > Create PDF/XPS

The PDF created has the right font, but the bold parts aren't formatted bold. I have used multiple pdf viewers.

My setup

- OS Name   Microsoft Windows 10 Home
- Version   10.0.19044 Build 19044
- Microsoft® PowerPoint® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2302 Build 16.0.16130.20298) 64-bit

What I have tried

- Google Sheets works
- Using colleagues computer works (same file, same export process)
- Exporting a different font that I have installed works
- Using MS Word export to PDF works with Open Sans + bold

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem using the font [Urbanist](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Urbanist/about). The solution for me was to install the **static** regular (and italic) font type and, doing so, **replace** the previously installed variable font types that are in the main folder of the font download. Afterwards, both Export -> Create PDF and Save as PDF worked fine from PowerPoint 2019 and also the MS 365 edition.

It seems that PowerPoint is not able to export bold prints of variable fonts to PDF.

Comment: this is a more general problem . . .  going to pdf Office only uses the "Regular" weight of Variable fonts, whether you use a heavier or a lighter one in your document.  I am thinking to make a self-answered q&a around this